# Why the image disappear

Tags: visualforce, images

I create a text(rich) field for an Object and put an image on this field. But when I want to show it on the page I wrote by VisualForce, the image turns to be a URL like this:

```
<img src="http://www.gdhtcm.com/uploadfiles/20170314103122705.png"></img>
```

How to show the image besides using Static Resource?

Comment: use `<img src={!your_link}/>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RichText Field the Image is stored as below. You have to use String operation to get the Image URL.

[image]

```
Book__c book = [SELECT Id, Rich_Text__c FROM Book__c LIMIT 1];
String imgTag = book.Rich_Text__c.substringBetween('<img', 'img>');
String imgUrl = imgTag.substringBetween('src="', '"');
String imgUrlFinal = imgUrl.replace('amp;', '');         
System.debug('imgUrlFinal : ' + imgUrlFinal);
```

Use this `imgUrl` in VisualForce page to show the image.

```
<img src="{!imgUrl}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks!But do you know why the image URL I get will include a string 'amp;' and I have to delete it to get the correct image URL?

Comment: You can remove the `amp;` by `replace` function of the String class.

Answer (score 1):

you can bind with Resource for fetching image from static resouce

```
<apex:image url="{!$Resource.**put your resource name here!!**}"/>
```